# Better word for something that comes back from being deprecated

Tags: vocabulary

So far all I have is 'reintroduced'. What is a better word?

Comment: From ODO: SYNONYMS
reintroduce, re-establish, restore, resurrect, relaunch, bring back, reinstall, reinstitute, regenerate, revitalize, resuscitate, breathe new life into, give a new lease of life to
reinvigorate, renew, awaken, wake up, rejuvenate, stimulate
archaic renovate

Answer (score 2):

Since deprecation is a change in status, consider *reinstate*.

> **reinstate** *verb*
>   Restore (someone or something) to their former position or state:
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reinstate)

As an example of *reinstate* used as an inverse of *deprecate*, consider the title of an IBM Knowledge Center entry:

- [Reinstating Deprecated Functionality](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8S5A_7.0.0/com.ibm.curam.content.doc/ServerDeveloper/c_SERDEV_DeprecationReinstateFunctionality.html)

Answer (score 1):

One word which Oxford does not [suggest](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372345/better-word-for-something-that-comes-back-from-being-deprecated#comment871550_372345) is ***rehabilitate***:

> 1.1 Restore to former privileges **or reputation** after a period of disfavour [my emphasis] [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rehabilitate)]

This seems a reasonable antidote to *deprecate:*

> 1.1 [regard as] obsolete and best avoided, typically because it has been superseded [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deprecate)]

Comment: **_Antidote???_**

Comment: Yes. The antidote to deprecation is rehabilitation. Perhaps that's stretching the normal use of *antidote*, but I like it.